# breaking html td when ngfor is applied

Tags: html, angular

```
<table>
<tr>
<th>Date</th>
<th>Products</th>
</tr>
<tr *ngFor="let x of orderdetails">
<td>{{x.orderdate}}</td>
<td *ngFor="let y of x.orderproducts">
  <span class="break">{{y}}</span><br>
</td>
</tr>
</table>
```

How can i break the line where span is given in td,
    css
    .break{
    word-wrap:break-word;
    white-space:pre-wrap;
    }
Royal Aspira should be placed below Royal Atoms
[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this

```
<table>
  <tr>
    <th>Date</th>
    <th>Products</th>
  </tr>
  <tr *ngFor="let x of orderdetails">
    <td>{{x.orderdate}}</td>
    <td>
      <div *ngFor="let y of x.orderproducts">
          <span class="break">{{y}}</span>
      </div>
      <br>
    </td>
  </tr>
</table>
```